# rust apk crashes on start with : dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Resume"

Tags: android, rust, android-ndk

I am trying to figure out how to write a Rust openxr app that uses `cargo apk run` to avoid having to write java shims.

I wrote a tiny app of my own (just tries to print some text and a pointer address) and pushed it to my Quest 2, but it crashes and the following appears in android studio's logcat window:

```
2023-04-21 10:39:13.570 2346-2346/? I/rust.flail: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2023-04-21 10:39:13.645 2346-2346/? E/rust.flail: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2023-04-21 10:39:13.795 2346-2346/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
2023-04-21 10:39:13.837 2346-2346/? W/NativeActivity: NativeActivity LoadNativeLibrary("/data/app/rust.flail-L__x2vGk9NMsv-15lUq_nw==/lib/arm64/libflail.so") failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Resume" referenced by "/data/app/rust.flail-L__x2vGk9NMsv-15lUq_nw==/lib/arm64/libflail.so"...
2023-04-21 10:39:13.837 2346-2346/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2023-04-21 10:39:13.837 2346-2346/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rust.flail, PID: 2346
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load native library "/data/app/rust.flail-L__x2vGk9NMsv-15lUq_nw==/lib/arm64/libflail.so": dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Resume" referenced by "/data/app/rust.flail-L__x2vGk9NMsv-15lUq_nw==/lib/arm64/libflail.so"...
        at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2048)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7436)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
2023-04-21 10:39:13.849 2346-2346/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2346 SIG: 9
```

I also tried https://github.com/rib/android-activity/tree/main/examples/na-winit-glutin and it crashes so fast android studio's logcat window doesn't even add it to the list of processes.

`adb logcat --buffer=crash` reveals what seems to be a similar problem

```
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime: Process: rust.na_winit_glutin, PID: 2751
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load native library "/data/app/rust.na_winit_glutin-voI8ttZEdfEewiGrxyfRRg==/lib/arm64/libna_winit_glutin.so": dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Resume" referenced by "/data/app/rust.na_winit_glutin-voI8ttZEdfEewiGrxyfRRg==/lib/arm64/libna_winit_glutin.so"...
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:178)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3277)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3443)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2048)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7436)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
04-21 10:41:06.519  2751  2751 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I am using `ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=~/Android/Sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653/` .

Is this just a universal problem with the `cargo apk` toolchain, or is there a configuration step I missed?

Answer (score 0):

A coworker pointed out that the symbol comes from libgcc.  I created a build.rs based on some stuff I saw online:

```
fn add_lib(name: &str, is_static: bool) {
    println!(
        "cargo:rustc-link-lib={}{}",
        if is_static { "static=" } else { "" },
        name
    );
}

fn main() {
    // work around dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_Unwind_Resume"
    add_lib("gcc", false);
}
```

But this by itself was not enough to make the code work.  I also had to use a different NDK:
`ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/home/thoth/Android/Sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529/`

I guess the Quest 2 is picky.

I managed to get past the UnsatisfiedLinkError and explode on a different problem.